# What is the proper way of introducing a pair of invertible complex functions $\exp$ and $\log$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to introduce a pair of invertible complex functions $\exp$ and $\log$ with the following properties:

$A$ being a branch (or strip?) of $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$:

$\forall a \in A \quad \exp(\log(a)) = \log(\exp(a)) = a$

$\forall a \in \mathbb{R}^* \quad \log(-|a|) = \log(|a|) + i\pi$

What is the proper way of introducing these two functions? I am especially concerned about the proper enunciation of the functions’ domains and codomains.

Furthermore, is there a proper way of introducing the “continuation” of the first property to a subset containing 0?

I am somewhat familiar with [complex logarithms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm), but I still struggle with the proper definition of domains and codomains using branches (strips?). I would like the definitions to be as precise and unambiguous as can be.

Comment: I am afraid that your functions cannot coincide with the usual exponential and logarithm. Because exponential is not injective on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, and so it cannot have an inverse and the first property cannot hold. 

What you can do is considering the restriction of the exponential to a strip $\{z=x+iy\ :\ y\in [a, a+2\pi)\}$. This function is a bijection onto $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I believe this is what I am looking for. Would you mind writing the full definitions in the form $f : A \longrightarrow B$ for both $\exp$ and $\log$ as an answer to the question? Thanks.

Comment: I disagree with the downvote, which, moreover, is not accompanied by a motivating comment. I'll see if I can convert my comment into an answer.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you! I edited the original question in order to clarify things.

Comment: This is a great case of [definition question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29618/how-to-properly-ask-a-definition-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first property to hold, the exponential must be restricted to a subset where it is injective. Now, the exponential is injective only on "horizontal strips" 
$$
A_\lambda:=\{x+iy\ :\ y\in [\lambda, \lambda+2\pi)\}, $$ 
where $\lambda\in \mathbb R$. This is a consequence of Euler's formula $$e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y + i \sin y).$$
For each fixed $\lambda$, since $\exp$ is a bijection of $A_\lambda $ onto $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, there is an inverse function $$\log_\lambda \colon  \mathbb C\setminus\{0\} \to A_\lambda.$$ WARNING: This function is discontinuous on the half-line $$\{re^{i\lambda}\ :\ r\ge 0\}.$$

For all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, it holds that 
$$\log_\lambda(-z)=\log_\lambda(z)\pm i\pi,$$
where the sign is chosen in such a way that $\log_\lambda(z)\pm i\pi$ stays in $A_\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.